# When should I resort to Eulers identity?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, solution-verification

I'm working on the following excercise:

> Calculate:
>
> $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin (x+\frac{\pi}{3})}{x^2+1}\operatorname dx$$

Using the contour-integral $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{z^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{i(z+\frac{\pi}{3})}}{z^2+1}\operatorname dz$ as follows:

[image: countour integration]

I've evaluated the integral using the residue theorem, i've proven $\int_{\Gamma_1}f(z)\operatorname dz \to 0$ and $\int_{\Gamma_2}f(z)\operatorname dz \to 0$.

But i've encoutered a problem on the remaining parts:

$$\int_{\Gamma_3} f(z) \operatorname dz = \int_R^\delta \frac{(-x)^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{i(-x+\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d (-x) \qquad \int_{\Gamma_4} f(z) \operatorname dz = \int_R^\delta \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{i(x+\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$

I think the second integral looks fine, but the first one gives me a headache.

#### option 1:

$$\int_R^\delta \frac{(-x)^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{i(-x+\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d (-x) =  -\int_\delta^R \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-i(x-\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$
$$=  -\int_\delta^R \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-i(x+\frac{\pi}{3})}e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$
$$=  -e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}\int_\delta^R \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-i(x+\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$

#### option 2:

$$\int_R^\delta \frac{(-x)^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{i(-x+\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d (-x) =  \int_\delta^R \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-i(x-\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$
$$=  \int_\delta^R \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-i(x-\frac{2\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$
$$=  \int_\delta^R \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-i(x+\frac{\pi}{3})}e^{i\pi}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$
$$=  -\int_\delta^R \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-i(x+\frac{\pi}{3})}}{x^2-1}\operatorname d x$$

Those solutions can't be equal can they? What causes this problem?

I think it has something to do with the $(-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is this equal to $-x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ or $e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}x^{\frac{1}{3}}$? When should I use Euler's identity?

### EDIT

Thank you for your reply Michael. I don't fully understand it. And I would like to illustrate with another related problem.

> Integrate over the curve $\Gamma$:
>
> $$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{z^{\frac{1}{3}}}{z^2+z+1} \operatorname dz$$

[image: extra problem]

After finding the poles, calculating the residue etc... I get to the remaining contours $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_3$.
$$\int_{\Gamma_1} f(z) \operatorname d z = \int_\delta^R \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x^2+x+1}\operatorname d x \qquad \int_{\Gamma_3} f(z) \operatorname d z = \int_R^\delta \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}{x^2+x+1}\operatorname d x$$

And once again the last integral can't be right. I guess it should be $x^\frac{1}{3}e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$?

But the reason is not clear. Why use $e^{i2\pi}$ in $\Gamma_3$ and **not** in $\Gamma_1$?

Comment: Both parts of $\sin x+\pi/3$ blow up on the outer circle so it is difficult to see what the contributions along the lines will be.

Answer (score 1):

In the region enclosed by the path, $(-x)^{1/3}=e^{i\pi/3}x^{1/3}$ by continuity.  The cube-root has a cut from the origin to $-i\infty$.
When you do the path in the lower half-plane, $(-x)^{1/3}=e^{-i\pi/3}x^{1/3}$ for the same reason, and the cube-root has a cut from $0$ to $+i\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is still not really clear however. I've added an additional problem with clarification of the exact 'problem' I'm having, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: When the path is in the upper half plane, $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$, so $0\leq(\theta/3)\leq\pi/3$, and the angle of $(-x)^{1/3}$ is $\pi/3$.  When the path is in the lower half plane, $0\geq\theta\geq-\pi$, so the angle of $-x$ is $-\pi$, and the angle of $(-x)^{1/3}$ is $-\pi/3$.